# Optimization Experiment technical error Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I'm trying to minimize the waiting time of people in the queue for a truck, I provided 25 trucks and only 1 is being used, so I did an optimization experiment with the objective of minimizing the waiting time in the queue with requirements of 95% utilization of trucks, so more than one truck at once could deliver people, when I run the optimization experiment it gives me this error: **OpenJDK 64 bit server warning there is insufficient memory of for the java runtime environment to continue** , although I used maximum available memory of 16343, how to solve this issue in order to give me the best number of trucks?
Thanks

Comment: Are you running any heavy programs simultaneously? Check from Task Manager for how much each program actually consumes. And when do you hit 100%

Comment: @YasharAhmadov Thanks, I tried to run it using other laptops but still won't give results

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Insufficient memory of for the java runtime simply means there is too much memory required to run the model.

More often than not the issue in AnyLogic is that there are too many agents, especially if you run some parameter variation or optimization experiments that tries to run multiple experiments in parallel which increase the memory requirement

One option is to convert as many agents to Java Classes as possible. First start converting all agents that are not used in Flow Blocks and where you don't need any animation.

Check this blog post for an example and more information

https://www.theanylogicmodeler.com/post/why-use-java-classes-in-anylogic